# If it possible to use filter_input (POST or GET) function inside a class in php

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to learn PHP Classes, and in my first Class I allready have trouble..

Code example:

```
class Loader
{
    public $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "action");
    public $dir = '';
    public $exceptions = '';
    function __construct($exceptions, $dir)
    {
        if(count($exceptions) > 0){
            if(isset($exceptions[$this->action])){
                $this->req($exceptions[$this->action]);
            }else{
                $this->req($this->action);
            }
        }
        require($args[$action].".php");
    }
    public function req($this->action, $dir){
        require($dir.$action.".php");
    }
}
```

And using it Like:

```
$e = array('task-list' => 'list', 'task-info' => 'info');
$loader = new Loader($e);
```

Is it possible to define $action inside a class with $_REQUEST variables? Or I should use it like:

```
$e = array('task-list' => 'list', 'task-info' => 'info');
$loader = new Loader($e);
$loader->action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "action");
$loader->load();
```

Comment: That is a matter of opinion. Some prefer to keep super globals out of classes, some consider them part of the language. I always approach it like this: If I were to write a test case for this class, could I initialize it easily with any test data I might want to use? Usually at that point I run into problems with any super global use.

Comment: but I receive an error in `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in Line` where $action is defined.

Comment: Ah sorry. Missed that somehow. Consider the order of execution: `new object` -> `__construct()` is executed -> returns to your code -> `$loader->action = foo` is executed -> `$loader->load()` is executed. Basically, you define action AFTER the constructor ran. Put the usage of `$this->action` into the `load()` method or supply it as argument to the constructor.

Comment: Member properties/variables have to be set to a constant value. If you need to use a function or do some other operations, do them in the constructor. Read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a function when declaring a property. You'll have to do it in the constructor like this:

```
class Loader
{
    public $action; // Removed it from here
    /* ... */
    function __construct($exceptions, $dir)
    {
        $this->action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "action");
                        // ^ and placed it down here.

        /* ... */
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)